# How to solve a recursion to find a closed form solution?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I have the following recursive process:

$f_n(t) = e^{t-1} f_{n-1}(1-(1-p)(1-t))$

The initial condition is that $f_0(t) = 1$

I calculated that $f_1(t) = e^{t-1}$

And then I also calculated $f_2(t), f_3(t)$ and $f_4(t)$.

However, the exponential terms just keep on increasing, and I am getting higher powers with non-linear terms.  I don't seem to see a pattern that can be deduced here.

Any advice on how to solve this recursion would be very helpful.

Comment: There is a pattern.  Let $g_n(s)=f_n(1-s)$ (for all $n$) and also write $q=1-p$ should give you a clearer view.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you very much for your insight.  I will work this through.  Ultimately I am trying to find the limit (as n tends to infinity) of fn(t).  For this, I was told that I need to solve the recursion.  So I think I need to get fn(t) in terms of n here.  Would you have any advice on how I can approach this?  Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: If you actually try it out you should arrive at the answer immediately.

Comment: I get f2(t) = e^((t-1)(2-p)) and f3(t) = e^(t-1) e^((2-p)(1-p)(t-1)).  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, I get a pattern that fn(t) = e^((t-1) (summation of q^i over i from 0 to n-1)).  Thanks a lot!!